# Well behaving custom switch or slider components nested in scrollable containers

Tags: codenameone

Some time ago I noticed that nested scrollable containers behave nice - for example several containers scrollable in their X-axis nested in a container that is scrollable in its Y-axis - and decided to take advantage of this by creating a custum composite swich component based on that and snapToGrid. 
However this never worked out nicely since snapToGrid had its problems.

When I talk about well-behaviour of nested scrollable components I mean you can tap on a nested scrollable component and it will just work well being able to scroll either the component itself or its also scrollable parent in the other axis.

What would I need to do in a custom scrollable component to achieve the same well-behaviour like it works with nested containers?

What I'd require of such a component - for example a switch - was beeing able to switch it horizontally while, once it notices that horizontal dragging threshold is reached, and not to affect its parent containers vertical scrolling then. The other case where, after a certain threshold of vertival scrolling in the parent component, it locks to vertically scrolling the parent container should already work, right?

By the way - with the out-of-the-box CN1 OnOffSwitch this does not work. When they are placed in containers nested in a container with BoxLayout.Y the this way represented list cannot be scrolled when tapping one of the OnOffSwitches and dragging vertically.

Comment: Perhaps the real question here should be: How to handle some pointer movements in a child component while handling others int a parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Events in Codename One are delivered from the system in the following order:

- The parent `Form` - e.g. you can override the `pointer*` callbacks
- `Form` listeners - e.g. `appPointer*Listener` on `Form`
- Builtin scroll if you are scrolling
- Focused component

I'm assuming you used focus to grab events which essentially blocks child components from grabbing the events.

If you did such a thing you need to deliver the events to the child yourself using the pointer callbacks on the given component. You can find the component at a given x/y coordinate using `getComponentAt(x, y)`.

Comment: This answer is strange. I don't understand a thing. 
No, nothing is focused. The thing is that all the pointerDragged events are intercepted by the leaf components and thus scrolling in the parent container is prevented. 
Think of a list of OnOffSwitch instances in a BoxLayout.Y scrollable container.
What i want to know is how to handle dragging in the X-axis in the child component and dragging in the Y-Axis in the parent so I can create custom components that behave just as well as nested Container components wher this just works

Comment: It seems like it is not possible to delegate pointer events to the parent containers since the pointer events there delegate to the children. That is unfortunate.

Comment: I guess it could be done by overriding Container.getComponentAt to return this when delegating back from a child but that would be messy

Comment: I tested the approach of delegating pointer events back to the parent by overriding the parent containers getComponentAt method and it works. But in my opinion there needs to be a documented way of doing this

Comment: I'm trying to find the internal detail that makes the locking to X or Y scrolling with nested scrollable Container instances

Comment: OK, I wondered why it is then when putting a Button component in an BoyLayout.Y Container that scrolling by dragging on one of the Button instances just works while doing the same with an OnOffSwitch doesn't.
Apparently that is because OnOffSwitch overrices pointerDragged and doesn't call super.pointerDragged. May I assume it is just a bug in the OnOffSwitch implementation? So if I did it right in my custom components it probably just work?

Comment: Or is it a fundamental problem of the Container scrolling approach taken by Codename One?

Comment: The question wasn't clear and this answer is the result. It's probably a bug in on-off switch. We have it in our queue for a rewrite